# Find maximum Log likelihood for repeated random variates

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, simulation

I have the following code

```
f[a_, b_] =ProbabilityDistribution[a/b^2*(1 - (1 + x/b) E^(-(x/b)))^(a - 1)*x E^(-(x/b)), {x, 
0, \[Infinity]}];
data = RandomVariate[f[13, 0.5], 25];
pars = FindDistributionParameters[data, f[a, b], {{a, 1}, {b, 1}}]
ll[a_, b_] = LogLikelihood[f[a, b] /. pars, data]
g[a_, b_] = NIntegrate[a/b^2*(1 - (1 + y/b) E^(-(y/b)))^(a - 1)*y E^(-(y/b)), {y, 0.01, 
x}]; 
h = DistributionFitTest[data, f[13, 0.5], "HypothesisTestData"];
h["TestDataTable", All]
Plot[{g[a, b] /. pars, CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[data], x]}, {x, Min[data], Max[data]}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, DotDashed}, PlotLegends -> {"Fitted", "Empirical"}, Exclusions -> None, AxesOrigin -> {Min[data], 0}]
```

Above code works fine, but I want to repeat above code fix number of times (say 100). Each time output will be different because of RandomVariate. I need such maximum likelihood parameters those maximize the LogLikelihood function (out of 100). FindMaximum may be used for this purpose. DistributionFitTest and following code should be applied only on maximum. 
I work on different ways but unsuccessful, please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data10 = RandomVariate[f[13, 0.5], {10, 25}]; (* 10 data sets from distribution f *)

lls= LogLikelihood[EstimatedDistribution[#, f[a, b], {{a, 1}, {b, 1}}], #] & /@data10
(*{-32.4994, -25.2268, -21.9671, -26.8963, -25.9164, 
   -22.8958, -26.5247, -24.9622, -33.9319, -28.6512}*)

maxll=Block[{k=1}, MaximalBy[Last][
                     With[{dist = EstimatedDistribution[#, f[a, b], {{a, 1}, {b, 1}}]},
                          {dist,k++,LogLikelihood[dist, #]} ]& /@data10]][[1]]
(* {ProbabilityDistribution[147.385 \\[FormalX] E^(-2.38603 \\[FormalX]) 
                  (1-(1+2.38603 \\[FormalX]) E^(-2.38603 \\[FormalX]))^24.8883,
                  {\\[FormalX],0,\\[Infinity]}],
    3, -21.9671}

 dtmll = data10[[maxll[[2]]]];
 distmll = maxll[[1]];

 h = DistributionFitTest[dtmll, f[13, 0.5], "HypothesisTestData"];
 h["TestDataTable", All]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{CDF[distmll,x], CDF[EmpiricalDistribution[dtmll], x]}, 
    {x, Min[dtmll], Max[dtmll]},
    PlotStyle -> {Dashed, DotDashed}, PlotLegends -> {"Fitted", "Empirical"},
    Exclusions -> None, AxesOrigin -> {Min[dtmll], 0}]
```

[image]